# How would I move code to a different class?

Tags: java, android

In the [SimpleApp](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp) tutorial, the author puts all of his code inside one class file.  Causing the rain and the bucket to be within it.

I tried just taking the code and putting it into another class but then I would have duplicate methods in my code, and logically it would be incorrect.  For example, I cannot have two create methods in a game.

**How would I take the *rain* or the *bucket* from the [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp) and put it into a different class?**

Comment: Your question is not very clear.Can you paste code that you want to move to a separate class. You should always move your code via refactoring tools provided in the IDEs.

Comment: Its all one in one class, scroll down to the bottom and you will see what i mean

Comment: It is against SO norms to talk about code that is not present here in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple: you could benifit from OOP style coding:
Just use a super class `RainBucket` that has all the methods in it with minimal code with each method.
Extend the other two classes from this super class and override in it the methods that your class wants to use, this way you would be acomplishing the following OOP rules:

1. Inheritence: when you derive from the super class two other objects:

   `class Bucket extends RainBucket {`

   `class Rain extends RainBucket {`
2. polymorphism: you can declare two objects from the same super class
   but by assigning to the two different derived classes as values like
   this:

   `RainBucket bucket = new Bucket()` and

   `RainBucket rain = new Rain()`

Comment: I think I did the Inheritance right but I don't understand the polymorphism that much. I created <RainBucket bucket = new Bucket();
 RainBucket rain = new Rain();> but I don't know where to put it, so I put it to the top. Then I put **bucket** and **rain**in both the _create_ and _render_ method but an error pops up saying that the method is undefined.  So whats the problem?

Comment: `RainBucket bucket = new Bucket();
 RainBucket rain = new Rain();

 @Override
 public void create() {

  Rain();
  Bucket();
 }

 @Override
 public void render() {

  Rain();
  Bucket();
 }`  It's under the main class

Comment: you are doing it wrong: first create the super class then the other to derived classes. then create another class that has the main method in it. in this main method you must write your code above.(accept my answer please ;-))

Comment: I created the superclass RainBucket, then i created smaller classes called Rain and Bucket.  My class, game, that has the main method is the main class.  It looks just like the tutorial but with the other added classes.  I'll accept your answer when it works :)

Comment: It still doesn't work... error: the method ... is undefined for the type Game

Comment: It doesn't go through.  E-mail delivery says its not a real address

Answer (score 0):

You'd abstract out the common functions into an [Abstract class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) or [Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) and then have both rain and bucket inherit from that class.

So, for your particular example, go through both classes, find all the common functions and abstract them into a superclass.

Comment: Can you provide an example or a link in which someone does this?>

Comment: @BluFire The links located in the post describe that. Look at the Abstract class link. It implements an abstract class called `GraphicObject` with a few functions. These are then inherited by `Circle`which `extends` it.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I didn't notice the links